# php variable scope

Tags: php, variables

I want to have `$count` as a global variable, I'm getting it to iterate fine, for one case but in another it always returns 0.

```
$count;

if(something)
{   
  if (somethingelse)
  {
    $result = mysql_query(SELECT * FROM Somewhere);

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
    {
       // this count is always zero  
       echo $count;
    }
  }
  else
  {
     $count = aValue;

     $anotherResult = mysql_query(SELECT * FROM SomeOtherTable); 

     while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($anotherResult)) 
     {
        $count++;
        // this iterates...
        echo $count;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Well yes, what else do you expect? You're not incrementing `$count` in your `if` case.

Comment: no but the point is I want the count amount to be read in the if statement that has been being incremented in the else. I guess I'm asking how to make this into a global variable...

Comment: Your code will *either* execute the `if` branch *or* the `else` branch. It won't execute both, so you're not going to get the result of the `else` branch in the `if` branch. What exactly do you want to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$count` variable is always zero for your first case because you're not incrementing it anywhere, you're just printing it out.

You might want to add a `$count++;` for the first case as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put $count++ in the loop that isn't working for you.

By the way, if all you need is a final count, you can just call mysql_num_rows() after mysql_query().  See http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php for details.